# Laravel queue daemon/worker not running registered shutdown functions

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I'm working on a Laravel 5.4 application. I create a few temporary files in my jobs, and guarantee that they are cleaned up by registering a shutdown function:

```
register_shutdown_function(function() use ($tempFilePath) {
    if(file_exists($tempFilePath)) {
        unlink($tempFilePath);
    }
});
```

The problem i have is that the registered shutdown functions from my jobs don't run when the jobs are queued and processed by a queue daemon/worker. They are run correctly when using `dispatchNow()`, so i'm pretty sure its queue related.

Is there a way to get the queue worker to run my shutdown functions after every job?

Comment: You need to set up some log calls and determine exactly what does not work. Just put some `\Log::info('some meaningful text');` around the code you are struggling with and debug it yourself. And FYI do not use unlink use file system instead https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem . You may also find useful https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#job-events

Comment: @Kyslik i've already made sure the shutdown functions aren't being called by trying to log some messages, they get written when not using the queue, but not when processed by a daemon. And i make an absolute path to the file using the laravel filesystem, and pass that to my shutdown function

Comment: You need to understand how queues work, its one big long running process (it actually depends on how you set up the worker). From the documentation on `register_shutdown_function` **Registers a callback to be executed after script execution finishes or `exit()` is called.** and notes **Shutdown functions will not be executed if the process is killed with a SIGTERM or SIGKILL signal. While you cannot intercept a SIGKILL, you can use pcntl_signal() to install a handler for a SIGTERM which uses exit() to end cleanly.**. I think that PHP will not run your register_shutdown_function because of it.

Comment: I would do a master queue class in which I would implement "delete method" which I would call in the end of the handle method. Its cleanest way and any person looking at it will understand what is going on. In past I did use magic methods and most of the team did not understand what is going on. From that point I try to be as explicit as I can be.